# Bringing PyQGIS and PyQt into already settled Anaconda Python environment in PyCharm

Tags: python, pyqgis, pyqt, windows-10, pycharm

I have Anaconda Python environment with different packages required for developing a QGIS plugin (including the [Plugin Builder Tool](https://g-sherman.github.io/plugin_build_tool/) etc.).

```
(qgsdata) C:\TempDaten\_dev\QgsData>conda info

     active environment : qgsdata
    active env location : C:\TempDaten\Programme\Anaconda3\envs\qgsdata
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\taras\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\taras\.condarc
          conda version : 4.12.0
    conda-build version : 3.20.5
         python version : 3.8.5.final.0
       virtual packages : __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : C:\TempDaten\Programme\Anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : C:\TempDaten\Programme\Anaconda3\etc\conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
          package cache : C:\TempDaten\Programme\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\taras\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\taras\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\TempDaten\Programme\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\taras\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\taras\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.12.0 requests/2.24.0 CPython/3.8.5 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19041
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

How can I extend it with PyQGIS and PyQt?

My technical propriety:

- Window 10 Enterprise Version 1909
- PyCharm 2020.3.3 (Community edition) in `C:/TempDaten/Programme/PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.3`
- QGIS 3.22.5-Białowieża in `C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.22.5`
- Anaconda3 2020.11 in `C:/TempDaten/Programme/Anaconda3`

I tried approaches offered in these articles:

- [Access QGIS API from Anaconda python environment using Conda-Forge](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310401/access-qgis-api-from-anaconda-python-environment-using-conda-forge)
- [Using PyQGIS in PyCharm 2020](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362874/using-pyqgis-in-pycharm-2020)
- [Why does QGIS 3.2 "native:extractvertices" algorithm not work properly in standalone script?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286281/why-does-qgis-3-2-nativeextractvertices-algorithm-not-work-properly-in-standa)
- [Alexandre Neto | Using QGIS from Conda](https://gisunchained.wordpress.com/2019/05/29/using-qgis-from-conda/)
- [Spatial Galaxy | Quick Guide to Getting Started with PyQGIS 3 on Windows](https://spatialgalaxy.net/2018/02/13/quick-guide-to-getting-started-with-pyqgis-3-on-windows/)
- [YouTube | QGIS Python Setting up PyCharm for QGIS Development (for QGIS 2.x)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qm0PCw9v5lI)

But nothing useful. I can not understand how to bring and merge together already existing Python environment in Anaconda with PyQGIS and PyQt.

I could run the created *'pycharm_qgis.bat'* file with the following settings:

```
@echo off 
@ECHO OFF 

set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.5

@echo off
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qt5_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\py3_env.bat"

@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\bin;%PATH%

set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES

set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000

set QGISNAME=qgis

set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins

set PYCHARM="C:\TempDaten\Programme\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.3\bin\pycharm64.exe"

set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\python
set PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python39
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages;%PYTHONPATH%

set QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\plugins\platforms
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr

start "PyCharm aware of QGIS" /B %PYCHARM% %*
```

and see the QGIS Python Interpreter in PyCharm:
[image: pycharm]

A simple command `from qgis.core import *` works.

[image: result]