# QGIS in conda environment

Tags: qgis, virtualenv

I have a new Conda environment and tried to install QGIS in the environment with the following command with the instruction of [anaconda documentation](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/qgis).

```
conda install conda-forge::qgis
```

The installation is getting hanged in the step Solving Environment.

I tried updating conda when with answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63734508/stuck-at-solving-environment-on-anaconda).

Still did not solve the issue.
Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Trying creating a new environment rather than installing into an existing one - `conda create -n newenvwithqgis -c conda-forge qgis`

Comment: Thanks. I have also tried this but still the same error

Answer (score 1):

Installation has worked in 2023 as described in the answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/450154/30184 but I confirm that it does not work for me today.

```
conda install conda-forge::qgis
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: /
```

There is no error but installation does not progress. The task manager shows that a Python process is using 100% of CPU of two cores and reserves 4.5 GB of memory. I waited for half an hour before stopping the process.

Comment: Are you sure that is not just slow conda being slow conda? I successfully installed `conda create --name qgistest qgis` in 2 minutes using [miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge) (based on [mamba](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba) instead of the standard conda.

Comment: I just tried installation with another computer with the same miniconda version and I had no problem at all. Weird.

Comment: Afaik they use different dependency solving strategies, maybe there is something broken there.